# Alfar 780 tablet not updated from ICS 4.0.3 to ICS 4.0.4

Tags: updates

My Alfar 780 tablet wasn't updated to ICS 4.0.4.

I downloaded 4.0.4.zip, and turned off the tablet. Then, I clicked the <kbd>power</kbd> + <kbd>volume up/down</kbd> buttons. It opened but did not show the menu to update.

Answer (score 1):

Change the file name of the 4.04.zip to update.zip and that should do it if you are able to boot into recovery.